# Add/Remove columns JTable problems

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablecolumn

I have a simple jtable for an employees list, I want the posibility of add and remove columns using a PopupMenu in the column header.

Please help me to konw what I have to do in the actionPerformed method to add or remove a column in my table. I'm getting an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EmployeeList extends JTable implements TableModel, ActionListener{

    private String[] allColumns={
        "First Name", "Last Name", "Age", "Address", "City", "Phone"
    };
    private ArrayList<String> visibleColumns;
    private JCheckBoxMenuItem[] columnCheck;
    private ArrayList<Employee> list; 
    private EventListenerList listeners;    

    public EmployeeList(){
        visibleColumns=new ArrayList<String>();
        visibleColumns.add("First Name");
        visibleColumns.add("Last Name");
        visibleColumns.add("Age");
        visibleColumns.add("Address");

        list=new ArrayList<Employee>();
        listeners=new EventListenerList();
        this.setModel(this);

        JPopupMenu menu=new JPopupMenu();
        columnCheck=new JCheckBoxMenuItem[allColumns.length];
        for(int k=0; k<allColumns.length; k++){
            columnCheck[k]=new JCheckBoxMenuItem(allColumns[k]);
            columnCheck[k].setActionCommand(allColumns[k]);
            columnCheck[k].setSelected(visibleColumns.contains(allColumns[k]));
            columnCheck[k].addActionListener(this);

            menu.add(columnCheck[k]);
        }
        this.getTableHeader().setComponentPopupMenu(menu);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        String command=evt.getActionCommand();
        JCheckBoxMenuItem item=(JCheckBoxMenuItem)evt.getSource();
        TableColumnModel m=this.getColumnModel();

        if(item.isSelected()){
            visibleColumns.add(command);
            m.addColumn(new TableColumn());
        }else{
            int index=visibleColumns.lastIndexOf(command);
            m.removeColumn(m.getColumn(index));
            visibleColumns.remove(command);
        }

        Object[] a=listeners.getListenerList();
        for(int k=0; k<a.length; k++){
            if(a[k] instanceof TableModelListener){
                TableModelListener oyente=(TableModelListener)a[k];
                    oyente.tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW));
            }
        }
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void loadList(ArrayList<Employee> list){
        this.list=list;

        Object[] a=listeners.getListenerList();
        for(int k=0; k<a.length; k++){
            if(a[k] instanceof TableModelListener){
                TableModelListener oyente=(TableModelListener)a[k];
                oyente.tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this));
            }
        }
        this.repaint();
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int pos){
        return (pos==2)?Integer.class:String.class;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int i){
        return visibleColumns.get(i);
    }

    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l){
        listeners.add(TableModelListener.class, l);
    }

    public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l){
        listeners.remove(TableModelListener.class, l);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int fila, int columna){
        return false;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object valor, int fila, int columna){    }

    public Object getValueAt(int m, int n){
        Employee e=list.get(m);
        String column=visibleColumns.get(n);

        if(column.equals("First Name")){
            return e.getFirstName();
        }else if(column.equals("Last Name")){
            return e.getLastName();
        }else if(column.equals("Age")){
            return new Integer(e.getAge());
        }else if(column.equals("Address")){
            return e.getAddress();
        }else if(column.equals("City")){
            return e.getCity();
        }else if(column.equals("Phone")){
            return e.getPhone();
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }

    public int getRowCount(){
        return list.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount(){
        return visibleColumns.size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();
        list.add(new Employee("Susan", "Madison", 45, "Manhattan 45", "New York", "487-39202"));
        list.add(new Employee("Jorge", "Perez", 45, "Revolucion 45", "Mexico city", "55-861254"));

        EmployeeList e=new EmployeeList();
        e.loadList(list);

        JFrame f=new JFrame("Admin");
        f.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(e));
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Employee class

```
public class Employee{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String phone;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String address, String city, String phone){
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.lastName=lastName;
        this.age=age;
        this.address=address;
        this.city=city;
        this.phone=phone;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }
}
```

The error that I'm getting...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:737)
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:480)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.getHeaderRenderer(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:693)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.paintCell(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:709)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.paint(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:685)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: One thing to note: separation of concerns. Don't have one class have too many responsibilities. Separate the model implementation from the table class. Perhaps the problem will become easier to track.

Comment: Separation is a little complicated because I have a bigger implementation with some business rules. 
I've just realized the change is done well, I just need to revalidate or repaint something or call some listeners. If I resize a column the change is shown well.

Comment: All I can say is irrespective of the business rules, you're overloading your class with too many concerns. [Separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/) is not a design principle to dismiss. It is a design principle to embrace. If you're not abiding by the principle, you will run into problems down the road. There's a good reason the model and the table were modeled as separate classes in Java. You should stick to the same principle.

Comment: *I want the posibility of add and remove columns using a PopupMenu in the column header.* - See: [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/) for a class that does this.